# Architecture and protocols to communicate with the remote server

Tags: c#, android, networking

How do I establish communication between Android based cell phone and a remote server via internet?

Which Architecture is best?
What Protocols should I use?

Purpose is to send and receive data (files) and notification from a server on a mobile phone.

Answer (score 2):

As android is basically linux (kind of)  you have all the options open.  However, (relatively) low level proptocols like TCP or UDP  are not always best choice,  as 
network connection is unreliable on mobile phones, and may change at any given time.

I have good experiences with REST-Services ( JSON over http[s] )  -  consumes less data than
XML based services.

If you like to receive notifications from server, you either have to perform periodic polling
( keep in mind power consumption!!!! )  or use some kind of cloud to device messaging ( it's also polling but done  trnasparently)